# Proving Normal Subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups

Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of a group $G$, where $H\subseteq K$. If $H$ is a normal as a subgroup (normal subgroup) of $G$, prove that it is also normal as a subgroup (normal subgroup) of $K$? 
 Definition of a normal subgroup:  A subgroup $K$ of a group $G$ is called a normal subgroup if $k\in K$ and $g\in G$ imply $gkg^{-1}\in K$. If $K$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, we write $K$ as a normal subgroup of $G$. 
 I need help proving this

Comment: well you know that every element in K is also in G, have a try at it its not that hard.

Comment: then pie($H$) is a subgroup of $G/K$ by the factor quotient group?

Comment: pie($H$)={$\text hH : h\in H$}

Comment: you are overcomplicating this, because H is normal $gHg^{-1}=H$ this works for every g in  G.Even for those $g\in K$

Comment: $K$ is a subgroup of $G,$ then all $k\in K,$ are in $G.$  $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G,$ then for all $g \in G, ghg^{-1}\in H$  Which means that $khk^{-1}\in H$

Answer (score 2):

You know that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ (noted as $H\trianglelefteq G$) and you want to prove that $H\trianglelefteq K$ given that $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$ and that $H \subseteq K$.

You have to prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $K$ and that it is also normal.

($H$ is a subgroup of $K$) I'll let you prove that.

(Normal) From $H\trianglelefteq G$, you know that for $h\in H$ and $g\in G$, $ghg^{-1}\in H$.

You want to prove that $H\trianglelefteq K$, so that for $h\in H$ and $k\in K$, $khk^{-1}\in H$. But you know that $K \subseteq G$. What then? **(EDIT)** Hint : Use the fact that $k\in K$ so $k\in G$.

Comment: $H$ is closed under conjugation?

Comment: You only know that $H$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ and that $K\subseteq G$ (i.e. any element of $K$ is also an element of $G$)

Comment: If $H$ is a subgroup of $K$, then for all $h\in K$ there exists $hgh^{-1}\in K$

Answer (score 2):

Let us first prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $K$. To do this, I will use the so called subgroup criterion:

> If $K$ is a group and $H$ is a non-empty subset. If for all $x, y \in H$ we have that $xy^{-1} \in H$ then $H$ is a subgroup of $K$.

$\textbf{Proof: }$ The prove is quite direct: We know that $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of $G$. Therefore they both contain the neutral element and this shows that $H$ is a nonempty subset of $K$.

For the second part of this statement, we do not even need that $K$ is a subgroup, but only that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$:

Let $x,y \in H$. Since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$, we have that $H$ is a group itself and hence $xy^{-1} \in H$.

$\textbf{Remark: }$ Note that in the above proof, we only needed that $K$ was a subgroup to be able to

1. use the subgroup criterion (only works if the bigger set is a group itself)
2. to show that $H$ is a non empty subset of $K$.

For your second part of the proof, let me show that $H$ is also normal in $K$.

$\textbf{Proof: }$ We have that $H$ is an normal subgroup of $G$, so for every $h \in H$ and for $\color{red}{\text{every } g \in G}$ we have that 
$$ghg^{-1} \in H$$
and since $\color{red}{K \subseteq G}$, it immediately follows that we have for all $k \in K$ that 
$$khk^{-1} \in H$$
which is exactly the condition for $H$ being normal in $K$.

I really hope this edited proof helps you out.

Comment: I gave an attempt showing $H$ is a subgroup of $K$. I think I need more

Comment: thank you so much @Student. I will remember this. I am still unsure of myself when doing proofs. I prefer the calculation part of Math in my studies

Comment: @behold: you should not be unsure: write down the definitions you know, possible helpfull results and most of all: do not overcomplicate things!

Comment: @behold: if any of the given answer was helpful, consider accepting one. This shows other stack users that your question has been solved :)

Comment: I write down my definitions a lot but incorporating into my proofs is where my problems at. Hopefully I can have a major breakthrough

Comment: Practice makes master (not sure if this is a correct saying, but you get my point) + you can always ask questions on this site (hints or verification of your solution, using the 'proof-verification' tag) :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is my attempt at showing $H$ is a subgroup of $K$ 
For all $k\in K$ and for all $h\in H$ then there exists $khk^{-1}\in K$ 
Hence, $H$ is closed under conjugation 
I am trying to use the conditions of a subgroup like 
 1) $H$ is nonempty 
2) $\forall$ $a,b\in H$ there exists $a,b^{-1}\in H$ 
 to prove $H$ is a subgroup of $K$

Comment: Normally you should make this a separate question, however, I will update my answer to give the full solution hoping this will help you.